# I want to get some particular cell from excel using selenium webdriver

Tags: excel

I am working with excel file with selenium webdriver. I can read the data from excel successfully but I want to get some particular Cell address and value from excel sheet using selenium webdirver.

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks in Advance.

Here is the Code.

```
String FilePath="D:\\ProUtility_Automation\\Transformation Logic.xls";
    try {
        Workbook wrk1 = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(
                FilePath));
        Sheet sheet1 = wrk1.getSheet(0);
        int totalNoOfRows = sheet1.getRows();
        int totalNoOfCols = sheet1.getColumns();
        //String a[][] = new String[1000][1000];
        for (int row = 0; row < totalNoOfRows; row++) {

            for (int col = 0; col < totalNoOfCols; col++) {
                System.out.print(sheet1.getCell(col, row).getContents() + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for reading particular cell value from excel, please import the right POI jars in your project, so that this code works correctly

```
private static XSSFCell Cell;
private static XSSFRow Row;
public static String getCellData(int RowNum, int ColNum) throws Exception{

try{

  Cell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum);

  String CellData = Cell.getStringCellValue();

  return CellData;

  }catch (Exception e){

  return"";

  }

 }
```

If you want the 2nd row, 3rd column cell value simply pass the parameters getCellData(1,2)---------> excel rows and columns start from (0,0)